# Debounce time lower than post request response time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

I have implemented a debounce function for my search box. But in some cases response to post request is longer then debounce function wait time and there so I get the wrong response displayed as a result. Is there a better solution to solve this than increasing the debounce wait time?

**EDIT:**

This is my try, using async function:

```
Vue.component('autocomplete', {
template: '#autocomplete',    
data: function() {
    return {
        searching_array: [],
        timeout: null,
    }
},

computed: {
    searching: function() {
        return this.searching_array.length > 0;
    }
},

methods: {    
    scheduleSearch: function() {
        if(this.timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }
        this.timeout = setTimeout(this.search, 500);
    },
    search: async function() {
        /*...*/

        this.searching_array.push(data.search);  
        await this.postRequest(/*...*/);
        this.searching_array.shift();
    }
}
```

And in template I have input field with `v-on:keyup="scheduleSearch"` action. Didn't include some parts of code as those are irrelevant to my question. In those parts I am adding content by which I am searching the database on a server. Also `this.postRequest(/*...*/)` returns response from a server as a `promise` function.
When computed `searching` is `true` I am displaying string `Searching...` instead of results.

And I am not using `axios`, but `this.$http.`...

Comment: You could modify the *debounce* function to wait for the request to finish before calling again.

Comment: Was thinking about that, but let's say user start typing something, than stops and wait for debounce time and then removes last char and enters new one. In the result box will be shown wrong results for debounce time + post request response time. I know that time is not long, but checking if there is a way to bypass it totally

Comment: Then you could cancel the request with an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) when the debounce function timeout has passed and when there is a request in progress. Then send a new request.

Comment: Right, didn't remember that. Thanks, gonna try it

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Hey, tell me, will I achieve same result by making function called as callback within debounce, asynchronus? Then I could await till post request returns a response

Comment: Don't know. Include your code into the question and let's take a look at it.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Here is the code, check it out, I am open for any questions